# Can allocation of big memory blocks be slower than that of small ones?

Tags: android, c++, performance, memory-management

At my workplace, we write cross-platform code in C++. All images must be allocated in advance because allocations are deemed too expensive (no, they are not inside tight loops). It is said that allocation of large memory blocks is slow on Android, while allocation of small blocks is much faster.

Is that true? Are big allocations slower on Android than small ones?

Comment: It's likely that with most allocation strategies allocating a small block is faster than allocating a large block, at least after memory has become a bit fragmented. That's due to at least two reasons. First, usually the C++ `new` uses a sub-allocator, and it's more likely that the sub-allocator can provide a small block directly, than that it can do that for a large block. Second, when a simple linear search of free blocks is involved, then a sufficiently small request can be satisfied by the first free block encountered, while a sufficiently large request requires traversal to the end.

Comment: IT sounds like something that you could write some test code for to convince yourself that it's expensive...or convince your colleagues that it's not.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf But why would Android use an algorithm where allocation works in O(n) and causes memory fragmentation? Buddy memory allocation has been invented 50 years ago, long before Android, according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_memory_allocation .

Comment: @Lev: Allocation schemes that involve linear search don't work in O(n). Buddy allocation reduces the number of possible block sizes to log(largest block size)/log(2), roughly, where free blocks of each possible size form a pool. Linear search can be involved here if a small size is requested and all the small size pools are currently empty.

Comment: OK, it's not O(n) for a well-defined n, but it's slower than O(1). Buddy allocation is O(1). Also, the number of possible block sizes is not an issue because you can always allocate a larger block than you need. Indeed, that's what happens most of the time.